# Is an algebra of sets on S containing all its finite subsets the power set of S?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let S be a nonempty set and F a nonempty family of subsets of S defined as follows: 1. if A is in F, A' is in F; 2. if A, B in F, A+B is also in F.

If one such family F contains every finite subset of S, is F the power set of S?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Let $S=\mathbb N$ and $F$ be the collection of all subsets such that either $A$ is finite or its complement is finite. This collection is an algebra and the set of even numbers does not belong to it.

Comment: Wait, can't we *build* this infinite subset of even numbers out of singletons (finite sets) using property 2?

Comment: No. Property 2) only allows you to take unions of finite number of sets. You cannot take infinite unions.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: we can apply the rule cumulatively an infinite number of times (assume all singletons are in F): { 1 } + { 2 } = { 1, 2 } (now { 1, 2 } is in F); { 1, 2 } + { 3 } = { 1, 2, 3 } (now { 1, 2, 3 } is in F); etc. This builds the whole |N, but you can build just even numbers.

Comment: @userr2684291 The fundamental difference between an algebra and a sigma algebae is you are allowed to take infinite unions in the latter but not in the former.